# How can I use fail2ban with ipv6?

Tags: ipv6, fail2ban

I have used the Fail2ban for a long time. I think this script is not able to manage the IPv6 -- or maybe it is working with IPv6?

How can I prevent IPv6 attacks with Fail2ban or do I have to search for another script?

Comment: fail2ban has had IPv6 compatibility since 2017. https://ncomputers.org/fail2ban

Answer (score 2):

v.0.10 of fail2ban came [with IPv6 compatibility](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/6893d5a8b78fbdf263df8a233b3b9ac343c7a02c/ChangeLog#L64-L65) included.